# Add result of php function to WP database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following function to create a member_id:

```
add_action('user_register', 'generate_member_id');
function generate_member_id($user_id){
    $unique_id = 1000 + get_current_user_id();
    $chapter_id = fetch_chapter();
    $member_id = "FAL-" . $chapter_id . "-" . $unique_id;
    
    return $member_id;
}
```

It appears to work fine and I can call the function from a shortcode and get the correct value.

Now I want to add the returned value to a database and have tried using

- `update_user_meta()`
- `$wpdb->update`
- `$wpdb->insert`
- `$wpdb->query`
  all with necessary arguments but nothing seems to work.

I expected this to do it, but it just generates a generic error that I am not able to debug (I have a problem with error logging):

```
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users" );
$generated_id = generate_member_id()
if( $users ) {
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'member_id', generate_member_id() );
    }
}
```

However if I change `generate_member_id()` to a string like `'memberId'`, it works and the database is updated. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Why can't I add' the result of the generate_member_id() function and to a WP database?

**EDIT**

```
add_action('user_register', 'fetch_chapter');
function fetch_chapter(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key = \'chapter_name\' AND user_id = '. $current_user->ID .' LIMIT 1');
    if ($result[0]->meta_value == 'Peregrine') {
           $result[0]->meta_value = 'PG';
    }elseif ($result[0]->meta_value == 'Barbary') {
           $result[0]->meta_value = 'BB';
    } 
     return $result[0]->meta_value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things I notice that could cause problems:

1. You have this line that (1) has no `;` at the end and (2) it doesn't look like you need it anyway - you don't use `$generated_id` anywhere:

```
    $generated_id = generate_member_id()
```

2. You are not passing the user_id into `generate_member_id` for your users in the loop calling `update_user_meta`...
3. ... but even if you did pass in the user_id, `generate_member_id` isn't using it anyway - it is using the current user id. That is the wrong value for the users in your loop.

You need to fix your `generate_member_id` function to work with the user_id parameter. I assume you want this function to work without one too, so it still gets the `get_current_user_id` is no user id is passed in:

```
add_action('user_register', 'generate_member_id');
function generate_member_id($user_id){

    // If no user_id is passed in, use the current user id
    if (!$user_id) $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $unique_id = 1000 + $user_id;
    $chapter_id = fetch_chapter_id();
    $member_id = "FAL-" . $chapter_id . "-" . $unique_id;
    
    return $member_id;
}
```

And then remove the erroneous `$generated_id...` line and pass the user_id to the `generate_member_id` in your `update_user_meta`:

```
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users" );
if( $users ) {
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'member_id', generate_member_id($user->ID) );
    }
}
```

Comment: `$generated_id = generate_member_id()` leftovers from trying all kinds of statements! Thanks @FluffyK, I think the second issue you mentioned was what had kept me running in circles. It works a treat now.

Comment: @eneimi I thought that might be the case :) FYI I just noticed I was missing a `;` myself so I’ve edited the code in my answer to fix it.

Comment: I have a situation now where the $member_id displayed in the frontend is accurate (specific for that user), but the member_id stored in the database is always using $chapter_id from admin (I am logged in as admin). I think I've mixed up $user and $current_user. Any thoughts @FluffyK ?

Comment: @eneimi Yes it does sound like you are getting the current user data instead of the "member" user.  You haven't included the `fetch_chapter_id` function here (I assume that's where you get $chapter_id for the user)  so I can't see what you're doing. However you have the `$user_id` now when you call `fetch_chapter_id` so you can pass it in to the function. If you need help more with it, you should ask a new question - each question on Stack Overflow should be about one single problem. If I'm on the site I'll take a look! but if I'm not, someone else might help :)